# how to show new select input only when select specific option and when select another options don't show by jquery? laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i'm trying to show new select input contains (states) options, when user select specific option a (USA) country, and when select another country non (USA) don't show the states select options i want in this case still hidden.

Route

```php
Route::get('/ajax-form', [AjaxController::class, 'index'])->name('ajax.index');
Route::get('/getState/{id}', [AjaxController::class, 'getState'])->name('ajax.state');
```

Controller

```php
class AjaxController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $countries['data'] = Country::orderby('name')
            ->select('id', 'name')
            ->get();

        return view('ajax.index', compact('countries'));
    }
    
    public function getState($countryId = 0)
    {
        $states['data'] = State::orderby('name')
            ->select('id', 'name')
            ->where('country_id', $countryId)
            ->get();

        return response()->json($states);
    }
```

Blade form with script:

```xml
@extends('layouts.app')
    
@section('form')
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label for="inputCountry">Country</label>
      <select class="country" id="inputCountry" class="form-control">
        <option selected>Choose...</option>
        @if ($countries['data'] && $countries['data']->count() > 0)
          @foreach ($countries['data'] as $country)
            <option value="{{ $country->id }}">{{ $country->name }}</option>
          @endforeach
        @endif
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="stateShow" class="form-row hidden">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputState">State</label>
      <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
        <option value='0' selected>Choose...</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
@stop

@section('script')
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#inputCountry').change(function() {
      var id = $(this).val();
      // Empty the States dropdown without first
      $('#stateShow').show();
      $('#inputState').find('option').not(':first').remove();
      // ajax request
      $.ajax({
        url: 'getState/' + id,
        type:'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
          var len = 0;
          if(response['data'] != null) {
            len = response['data'].length;
          }
          if(len > 0) {
            // Read data in the state option that related with country
            for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
              var id = response['data'][i].id;
              var name = response['data'][i].name;
              var option = "<option value='" + id + "'>" + name + "</option>";
              $('#inputState').append(option);
            }
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
@stop
```

the above script doing, when i select any country, the hidden (states) select is shown, i want it shows only when i select (USA) and non that still hidden

could you help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `inputCountry` select-box i am assuming `{{ $country->name }}` is country name so you can use `$(this).find("option:selected").text()` to get this value and then compare it with `USA` if they are equal show your div else hide it.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('#inputCountry').change(function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  var text = $(this).find("option:selected").text().trim() //get text
  if (text == "USA") {
    $('#stateShow').show(); //show
    $('#inputState').find('option').not(':first').remove();
    //your ajax call put here ....
  } else {
    $('#stateShow').hide(); //hide
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label for="inputCountry">Country</label>
      <select class="country" id="inputCountry" class="form-control">
        <option selected>Choose...</option>
        <option value="{{ $country->id }}">Abc</option>
        <option value="{{ $country->id }}">USA</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="stateShow" class="form-row hidden">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputState">State</label>
      <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
        <option value='0' selected>Choose...</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
</form>
```